# Linear Algebra Scalar and Vector Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I have a problem with one part of a question. I just need help with part b. How would I go about applying the equation to find the scalar and vector projection of v2 onto v1? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Recall the formulas for scalar and vector projection (respectively), in this case, will be $\frac{\langle v_2,v_1\rangle}{||v_1||}$ and $\frac{\langle v_2,v_1\rangle}{||v_1||^2}v_1$. You have a definition of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle,$ and $||x||^2=\langle x,x\rangle.$ All you need to do is to compute these quantities.

Answer (score 0):

I will extend the previous answer and show how it is computed. As stated, we need to calculate the projection of $v_2$ onto $v_1$. To do this, we use the dot-product, denoted $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle$. This is simply

$\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle = 2 * 1 + 2 * 0 = 2$.

Now, we project $v_2$ onto $v_1$, denoted $v_2^{||v_1}$, using the formula from previous answer:

$v_2^{||v_1} = \frac{\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle}{\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle} * v_1 = \frac{2}{8} * \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0.25 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Note that $\langle v_1, v_1 \rangle$ is the same as $||v_1||^2$.